# Apache Regex How To Get This Value

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess

I have a URI like this:

http://example.com/demo/makemoney?matchtype=chancee&network=agagag&ifmobile=1&placement=nyc&adposition=111&copy=25&pid=123&zid=231&mid=234&cid=342&param1=zaleemm&param2=vatansvr

I want to get makemoney and after "?" character values. In my .htaccess file write this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^demo/(.*)?(.*)$ demo.php?utm_campaign=$1&$2 [L,NC]
```

But only utm_campaign I get in $_GET super globals. What's true regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query string is separate from the request uri. In your case you only want to add a value to it, so you can use the `[QSA]` (Query String Append) flag to pass the entire query string with the value you captured from the URI

Try:

```
RewriteRule ^demo/(.*)$ demo.php?utm_campaign=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you're not getting anything after utm_campaign is because the first matching group is made optional by the question mark. Try escaping the question mark like this:

```
RewriteRule ^demo/(.*)\?(.*)$ demo.php?utm_campaign=$1&$2 [L,NC]
```

Does that help?

Comment: this rule redirect request to unrelated page (homepage)

Comment: @Mesuti, I just copied the format for the url and rule in your question. The important difference is the backslash "\" before the question mark "?". Could you give an actual URL example if you want the exact rule? Thanks.